# debug strange characters returned by symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm not sure how to debug this, or even how best to describe the problem, but all symfony requests are returning strange characters at the beginning of every page. Example:

Â§{"id":"c8184631","version":0.1}

This should be a json response. Those two characters appear at the beginning of every response no matter the bundle or controller. But only happens on symfony, regular PHP on that server is fine.

This doesn't happen locally. I'm unsure how to start debugging this or even which questions to ask.

Comment: Nothing to do with UTF-8?

Comment: @andy how would I test that?

Comment: Check out those characters in a hex editor, try using `grep` across your project for the specific bytes found. Maybe a BOM issue.

Comment: I'd work my way up the files that are being called, one of them is printing that .

Comment: @Patrick you're right. I accidentally committed the § character before <?php in app.php. Found it by deploying older commits until that character wasn't returned, then checking the commit diff. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are some files with different encoding (utf-8 or iso-8859-13), that happened to me before, but I was not using symfony2, just php.

What I did was open every file and changed the file encoding to utf-8.

You can check the encoding for each file for example in "Notepad ++" 
Encoding->Convert to UTF-8.

It worked for me.